# Common name for variable and constant

Tags: variables, constants, semantics

In programming (and math) there are **variables** and **constants**. Is there a name to describe both of them?
I was thinking **value**, but that's not it. A value is what variables/constants contain, not what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it a **symbol**. From [google](http://www.google.com/search?&q=define%3asymbol):

```
sym·bol/ˈsimbəl/Noun
1. A thing that represents or stands for something else, 
   esp. a material object representing something abstract.
...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different terms I use, depending on context. I'll give you a list of the terms I (might) use - sometimes I'll just default to calling everything 'variables'.

Field - a variable or constant that's declared as part of the class definition.

Parameter - one of the inputs specified when defining a method in a class.

Argument - the actual value that you provide for a parameter when calling a method.

Method variable - a variable declared inside a method.

Method constant - a constant declared inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know Its called a field

Comment: I think that is only when it's an instance variable/constant in an OOP language

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- maths and logic: [term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_%28logic%29)
- programming: [l-value and r-value](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023341/Lvalues-and-Rvalues).

Answer (score 1):

How about "data item"?

One definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_item
Example showing it can be used for local variables/constants as well (unlike "field" or "attribute"): https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC222/EclWin/GUID-A3B817EE-1D63-4F67-A62C-61DE681C6719.html

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, the [attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_%28computing%29) can be both a variable and a constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Identifiers**

> In computer languages, identifiers are tokens (also called symbols) which name language entities. Some of the kinds of entities an identifier might denote include **variables**, **types**, **labels**, **subroutines**, and **packages**.

**Symbols** are super set of **Identifiers**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier#In_computer_languages